# Is it possible to add Merriam-Webster to Mac's Dictionary app?

Tags: macos, dictionary

I searched for "misclassify" in Dictionary.app and it couldn't find anything. I Googled it, and Google gave the a nice definition in the first result, from Merriam-Webster.

Is it possible to add Merriam-Webster to Mac's Dictionary app?

Comment: If you add a uk english dictionary to the checked items in dictiionary.app preferences you should get an entry for that word.

Comment: Voted for this question to be reopened because the supposed duplicate has only a link-only poor quality answer.

Comment: @Alper This doesn't make it less of a duplicate. It might be an incentive to improve said answer though :-)

Comment: One is about adding an Old English dictionary and the other is about adding Merriam Webster. They sound like different questions to me.

Comment: Yes, I'd read the Old English question before posting this and think it's a different question.
This question is not about whether it's possible to add custom dictionaries to Dictionary.app, it's about adding Merriam-Webster in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Dictionary app uses data in its own special format. It is possible to create dictionary files using Xcode; and there are scripts to convert other dictionary formats into Apple's own data type.

So, possible: yes. However, I don't think anyone has done it. MW have their own app on the App Store. It's possible that they have restrict access to their data.